# How to change the background colour of specific menu items in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I've seen various questions on how to change the background colour of all menu items of the action bar overflow menu, but my case is that I need to set a custom background for *specific* menu items in the **side navigation drawer**.

Here is what I have at the moment (with the menu items that require a background manually highlighted in red):

[image: My navigation drawer]

As you can see, I've already changed the text colour of the menu items in question to orange. I had to do this programmatically - like this:

```
MenuItem menuItem = ...;
int colorOrange = ...;
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorOrange), 0, s.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

But how can I change the background colour of these menu items?

For completeness, here is the corresponding section of my **menu_nav_drawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        ...

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_why_upgrade"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/why_upgrade_qm" />

        <item
            android:title="@string/latest_and_local">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_gmo_news"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_announcement_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/latest_gmo_news" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_local_gmo_free"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/local_gmo_free" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>

        <item
            android:title="@string/miscellaneous">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_settings"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/settings" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/share_this_app" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_leave_review"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/leave_rating_feedback_tc" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_the_holistic_works_website"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/the_holistic_works" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>

        <item
            android:title="@string/legals">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_privacy_policy"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_terms_and_conditions"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/terms_and_conditions" />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/menu_item_disclaimer_and_copyright"
                        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_copyright_white_24"
                        android:title="@string/disclaimer_and_copyright" />

                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>

    </group>


</menu>
```